# Passing entire html Table data to web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a Html table grid (multiple rows) that generating rows dynamically on button click(run time). i have to pass entire html table data to web method via jquery ajax.
Snapshot is attached for more detail.
[Form with asp.net controls and html table grid with multiples rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFbwf.png)

Comment: Please post the **relevant** code, **rendered** HTML (not code that generates HTML) relevant to the issue, preferably in a working snippet demonstrating the problem so we can see what might be the cause. Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass the values from the form inputs in the table? Passing the entire table HTML is rather... odd.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes. how i can pass forms inputs in table?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the code to convert the table to json. `http://johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/`

After converting your table to json, then use the below code to call the web method.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'mypagewhichhavewebmethod.aspx/mywebmethod',
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'tablejsonData' : " + myjson + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
                  alert("Start!!! ");
               },
    success: function (data) {
                 alert("a");
              },
    failure: function (msg) { alert("errrrrr!!! "); }
    });
```